# How to read form elements in php?(Not form attributes)

Tags: php, forms

I'm writing a function which will crawl all URLs from the base URL and read the html content of each and every page,and will search for the '`form`' tag to `findout` the `login` page `url`, and should apply the credentials to proceed the crawl for the authenticated pages too.

So far i can be able to read the html contents of each page and got the form attributes like method(i.e post/get) and action.

Now I want to check the inside of '`form`' tag for any '`input`' tags to get their attributes like name to apply credentials and should trigger the submit button.
If I use

> ```
> $doc->loadHTML($html_data);
>
> $inputtags= $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
> ```

I will get all the input tags from the page.

But I need to get the input tags only from the form tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) or `pq` for short is a jQuery-like library for PHP. There are ways to do this without using `pq` but `pq` sounds fun and likely 2 lines of code to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

use `simple dom parser` to do so ,it `selector` work same like `jquery`  which will help your get `input` element in side `form`

please check this link http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/